# Ubuntu 16.04 Unity: cannot disable TOP and BOTTOM sticky edges

Tags: unity, display, settings, ccsm

Disabling sticky edges for left and right sides of the display was easy.  I've set that to off.  Using CCSM, I set edge stop velocity to 1, but still the edges of Thunderbird and Chromium stick to the top and bottom in Unity.  How do you disable that? Thanks in advance.